# Prove $EXP \subset E^E$

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity

I'm trying to prove $EXP \subset E^E$ (strictly).

I believe I need to construct my own $A \in E^E$ and show that $A \notin EXP$, but I cannot think of a smart way of doing that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class $E^E$ contains 2E, which is the class of problems solvable in iterated exponential time. The reason is that the E oracle can be applied on a padded input of exponential size. The time hierarchy theorem separates 2E from EXP.

Comment: To elaborate, are you saying we can express $E$ in terms of $DTIME(...)$ (i.e without an oracle), and show that it's strictly greater then $EXP=DTIME(2^{n^c})$? Because then, the conclusion comes directly from the time hierarchy theorem.

Comment: Not exactly, though perhaps a more refined statement to that effect might hold.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80988/discussion-between-galah92-and-yuval-filmus).